# React - Display loading screen while ajaxing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unlike some of the other questions, my component has already fully loaded. I have managed to create the loading screen BEFORE the component was loaded, but now I'm unsure of how to create it after.

What I'm trying to do right now is make an ajax call which then changes the state/(redux store) which should then display my loading screen.

e.g. a child component calls an ajax:

```
let url = "src/php/search.php";
axios.get(url, {
params: {
  report_id: data.id,
  type: "get_report"
}
})
.then( r =>
  {
    console.log(r.data);
    this.props.dispatch( { type: "set_loading", payload: false } );
    this.props.dispatch({ type: "set_report", payload: r.data });
    this.props.router.push('/form/start');
  }
);
```

This is the parent render:

```
render()
{
  return (
    <div style={{padding: "0 5px"}}>
      <LoadingScreen loading={this.props.loading} /> <<<<< The loading screen
      <div style={{padding: "0"}}>
        <Link activeClassName="active" className="default bottom-radius" to='main'>Main Menu</Link>
        <Link activeClassName="active" className="default bottom-radius" to='search'>Search</Link>
        <a className="bottom-radius" style={{ float: "right", color : "blue", backgroundColor: "red", padding: "5px", cursor : "pointer" }} onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>
      </div>
      <div style={{paddingTop: "10px"}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

const App = connect(
(store) =>
{
    return {
      "user_id": store.component.user_id,
      loading: store.component.loading
    };
}) (AppComponent);
```

I was expecting the `this.props.loading` to turn true, which then displays the loading screen, which then goes away on the `then` in the child component. But instead nothing happens. Will I need a middleware for this instead?

Comment: Dont you need to conditionally render? `this.props.loading ? <LoadingScreen> : {render your children}`

Comment: Nah, I just have it as a `display: none` while it's not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `dispatch an action` to set the state to loading when `you send an ajax request`. Instead you are dispatching an action in the `success call` of ajax, soon after which you send the `set_report` action which overrides the `set_loading` action even before you notice.

Use the ajax call like

```
axios.get(url, {
params: {
  report_id: data.id,
  type: "get_report"
}
})
.then( r =>
  {
    console.log(r.data);
    this.props.dispatch({ type: "set_report", payload: r.data });
    this.props.router.push('/form/start');
  }
);
```

and call this dipatch where you send an ajax call

```
    this.props.dispatch( { type: "set_loading", payload: false } );
```

Comment: sorry, seems like I had posted incomplete data. I have the props dispatch before the ajax call and I just realised what's wrong. It's not showing up because jquery's DataTables is actually hiding my text, as it's appearing beneath it. But I'll mark since it's appropriate to the question

Comment: No problem, glad that you figured it out :)